# If Condition Not Working using variable

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have assigned all condition to a variable(a) and using the same variable in condition, but is is not working, when we copy all the criteria given to the variable and use it directly in the condition it is working.

```
a = "Trim(Mid(""" & sNextLine & """," & UserForm1.TextBox5.Text & "," & UserForm1.TextBox6.Text & ")) " & con & " " & """" & UserForm1.TextBox8.Text & """"
If a Then
  a = b  
end if
where sNextLine ="061001    00100 0002017001    001.00 00004001  61A00     000000000", UserForm1.TextBox5.Text=1, UserForm1.TextBox6.Text=3,con ="=", UserForm1.TextBox8.Text="061"
```

Please Help me with this. if any problem in the question or code please ignore. i'm new here.

Comment: A string is not a boolean.  (VBA code is compiled, then run.  You can't "write code" into a string variable at run time and then just use that string variable instead of code.)

Comment: is that any other way i can use? because i have some hundred of condition @YowE3K

Comment: You could write code that creates VBA code from your strings, puts that code into a module, then calls it.  (I think!)  Definitely not recommended for someone not **very** familiar with VBA.  (I wouldn't even attempt it myself unless I was desperate and had a lot of time to spare to play around with it.)

Comment: IF a is what?  Non-empty?  What is that line trying to say?

Comment: Try: `IF Application.Evaluate(a) Then`

Comment: @mooseman It's trying to say `If Trim(Mid("061001 00100 0002017001 001.00 00004001 61A00 000000000",1,3)) = "061" Then`

Comment: Scott's suggestion of using `Evaluate` will probably work, **providing** you stick to Excel functions in your string and don't try to use VBA functions.

Comment: IF Application.Evaluate(a) Then is not working

Comment: `If Application.Evaluate(a) Then` works for me for that specific example.  What is the value of `a` when it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @mooseman, `if a then` is a valid statement. it checks if `a` is `true`    ... the OP did not use it correctly here

Comment: it is not working. anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: @jsotola, I was mostly asking what that statement was supposed to check for.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you;

> a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Mid(sNextLine, TextBox5.value,
>   TextBox6.value))
>
> If a = TextBox8 Then
>
> a = b
>
> End If